# R.java missing can't compile

Tags: android, eclipse

I import my project into eclipse, but compiler shows error because R.java file is missing.

This is what appears in the log screen:

```
[2012-01-11 15:35:41 - Check-list-AndroidApplication1] ERROR: Unable to open class file C:\Workspace\Android\Check-list-AndroidApplication1\gen\com\mobyfactory\uiwidgets\R.java: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you clean after importing?

Comment: You can just try to clean/refresh or recompile again

Comment: Try what guys above said. If doesnt work, have you check your project for errors? It may have errors that prevent XML to parse.. so R isnt build, and is missing...

Comment: If you don't understand clean/refresh, you can simply delete the `gen` folder. This should not harm your project and alleviate you from the R.java file missing problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do what @Metalfrekans said again, and set Build Automatically, then saved the file and Eclipse should generate the R.java

Comment: I unchecked build automatically,then set it and build it again and it works

Answer (score 2):

If do you have R.java, copy the content of R.java and delete from the project. And create new R.java in gen folder. Paste you copied content to it.

If you don't have R.java, create a new project. Copy the content of activity.java files and .xml files except R.java to new project.

Comment: Why would you create R.java by hand?

Comment: Sometimes compiler doing this. You can try normal people solutions: Reset your computer :) or close ide and open again. And these are now working, delete your compiler and install again. Joking.
Check your other errors. R.java missing error may be depens on other errors.

Comment: Did you check your java file. Sometimes Eclipse import R.java in java file without asking you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you have a problem with R.Class is because of some layout xml file, or some image adcionada the project with the name outside the patterns with spaces like "image name" instead of "image_name" etc..

revise it and try to go on project -> clean that if the problem is that the R.Class will be recreated automatically.